# NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I've looked all over Stack Overflow and I cannot find an answer for this.

This is my code:

```
NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)[NSKeyedArchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

When I call this, I'm getting this error:

```
No known class method for selector 'unarchiveObjectWithData:'
```

This is running on iOS, what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

NSKeyedArchiver doesn't have an unarchiveObjectWithData method.  You probably want to use NSKeyedUnarchiver.